# Why is the text sometimes showing, sometime not in the webpage?

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts

I have this layout i'm working on, and the text sometime doesn't show. But if i refresh it a few times, it shows.

The Chrome console output is:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

And only this, so, no 404, no 503, no 500, no errors at all.

So, i'm using some web fonts, still, they're local, here is my font-face:::

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(../font/OpenSans.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(../font/OpenSans-Bold.woff) format('woff');
}
```

And i have absolutely no idea why this is happening, someone might have run into something like this already... so...

Comment: Might be this very painful Chrome/Chromium bug : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336170

Comment: I don't think so. i have "font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;" on my body tag, so at least it should show some text, won't it? Is shows no text at all... and also no SVG Icons, i forgot to mention this

Comment: Correction: icons are showing!

Comment: It's related to the webfonts, i tried using only 'Tahoma' and it's always showing!

Comment: notice the url in your custom font. it says ../ one folder up, so if your pages are located not on the same level, the font will only load for pages that are on a folder which is on the same level as fonts.

Comment: i don't think it's url related, 'cause it's in the same page

Comment: I have the very same bug, couldn't solve it yet. It doesn't show once in a while. So by passing the mouse over it, sometimes make the text appear, but that doesn't work every time. My console outputs the same thing as well.